# How to fix issues sending data from web page to chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to pass data from my webpage to the chrome extension.

manifest.json (I am trying to do this in my local environment first)

```
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://localhost/*"]
  }
```

In listen.js (a background script):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor)
        alert('test2');
        alert(request.openUrlInEditor);
  });
```

None of the alerts display above.

I got the extension ID of the unpacked chrome extension by viewing the ID when I navigate to chrome://extensions/. In my webpage in localhost environment

```
// DEVELOPMENT extension ID
var editorExtensionId = "fppgjikaoolnlcmdjalbfkmlcadcckmb";

var url = 'test';
// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

When I run this. in the browser, I get an error saying:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

I'm not sure where to begin debugging this.

Comment: 1. Is `localhost3000` a typo? Try without the port number. 2. `alert('test1');` inside function parameters is a syntax error, make sure you know [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029), 3. `response` may be also undefined in case the extension is disabled so you shouldn't assume it's always present.

Comment: @wOxxOm I also changed the example to match what is in https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging and I still get the same error.

Comment: What errors do you see in `console.log`? Also try replacing `alert` with `console.log` and see if it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After making a few changes in your code I am able achieve your goal.

See below the complete code.

> manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CS to Bg Communication",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["listen.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames" : true,
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://localhost/*"]
  }
}
```

> listen.js - the background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    blacklistedWebsite = 'http : / / yourdomain . com /';
    if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
      return;  // don't allow this web page access
    if (request.openUrlInEditor) {
        alert('test2 - ' + request.openUrlInEditor);
        sendResponse({"success": true, "AckFromBG": "I have received your messgae. Thanks!"}); // sending back the acknowlege to the webpage
    }
});
```

> contentscript.js  - the content script - actually does nothing

```
console.log("this is content script");
```

> web-page.html - The local web page

```
<html>
    <body>

        This page will will send some message to BG script

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // DEVELOPMENT extension ID
            var editorExtensionId = "fjaedjckfjgifecmgonfmpaoemochghb"; // replace with your extension ID
            var url = 'test';
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (!response.success)
                    handleError(url);
            });
            function handleError(url) {
                console.log(url);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Summary of changes:

- Defined `blacklistedWebsite` -  this was undefined.
- Added `sendResponse({"success": true, "AckFromBG": "I have received
  your messgae. Thanks!"});` to send back the acknowledgment to the
  webpage.
- Define `function handleError(url) {
                 console.log(url);
             }` this was not defined.

That's it. Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: How would you do this in manifest v3?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates that `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is executed. This means that external messaging is set up correctly: otherwise, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` wouldn't be exposed to your page's code.

I think the problem is here:

```
if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
  return;  // don't allow this web page access
```

I suspect the problem is `blacklistedWebsite` being undefined; the code fails with a ReferenceError and no meaningful response is being sent. Since the `onMessage` listener terminates (even with an error), the calling code gets an `undefined` response.

Check your [background console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10257301/934239) to confirm if that's the case; if you copied [this partial example code](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage) but aren't using this blacklisting functionality, delete this branch.

*In future, please make sure you understand what every line of code you copy does!*